# How can I use google calendar with Windows Live Mail?

Tags: google-calendar, windows-live-mail

I'm currently trying to integrate my google calendar into Windows Live Mail.

What I have so far:
I went online to the hotmail calendar and subscribed there per iCal to the google calendar. It gets added and displayed properly in Windows Live Mail, but I cannot add new entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you used Outlook, you could sync it directly using [Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot add new entries via iCal interface to Google Calendar as it's read-only and Windows Live Mail doesn't support Google Calendar's API.

The solution would be to either use another program that does support Google Calendar (like [Thunderbird](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-integrate-google-calendar-into-thunderbird/) or [Microsoft Outlook](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563)) or to [use Windows Live Mail with Hotmail Calendar](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-calendar-mail-using). Also you can use Google Calendar directly even if your computer is not connected to the Internet. You just need to [enable offline mode](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1340696).

Hope that helps.